# Jump if equal x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, ascii

```
    mov answ, 11
    lea bx, answ    ;scanf
    mov ah, 0ah
    int 21h


    cmp [bx], 79h
    JE L1
```

I don't understand why isn't it jumping to L1 even though I'm entering 'y' pls help me I'm new to x86 assembly programming.

Comment: I thought I'd point out a few things regarding your code: Since `cmp mem,imm` is ambigous it would be a good idea to write `cmp byte [dx], 79h`, or `cmp byte ptr [dx],79h` depending on the assembler used. Also, using `'y'` as an immediate instead of `79h` should be supported by any decent assembler, and makes the code much clearer.

Comment: On x86 the 16 bit register dx, cx and ax can not be uses as an address register between brackets[]. Only bx, si, di, bp and sp and all of the 32 bit register on 386+.

Comment: Usefull instructions are: "cmp byte[bx],79h" "cmp byte[si],79h" or "cmp byte[di],79h" ; compare the byte with DS:BX, DS:SI, or DS:DI

Answer (score 0):

0ah instruction accepts buffer at DS:DX, and populates it with entered chars. So you probably need

```
lea dx, answ
...
cmp [dx], 79h
```

Besides, buffer is populated with its length and other information, if you need to read just one char - use 07h - direct char input without echo. char will be put in AL

http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah0a

Comment: I tried using lea dx,answ cmp[dx],79h but it doesn't work. Emu 8086 says that it is probably an undefined var, but doing this cmp answ[2] seems to work can you explain it to me? if you ever know why

Comment: Oh, that's correct. cmp compares word, to compare with byte you would probably need cmpb. according to spec, answ[2] holds first byte of input string. answ[0] holds size of buffer, and answ[1] is actual number of chars stored in buffer.